# How to capture Key press event for a text box?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a winform application which has two text boxes and a button. If the control focus is on any of the text boxes and user clicks keyboard "enter" button. The button event should invoke.

The issue is I couldn't find the TextBox_KeyDown to capture the "Enter" key press. In the Visual Studio editor, KeyDown,KeyPress,Keyup properties are empty.

Comment: "I couldn't find the TextBox_KeyDown" sounds to me like you need some reading. You can start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things. It sounds to me like you just need to set the `AcceptButton` on the `Form` to the button you want clicked when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will be handled automatically for you.

Second, if that's not the case, then you need to set the `KeyPreview` to `true` on the `Form` and handle the `ProcessCmdKey` method on the `Form`:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks neoistheone. This is what I want

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this?

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: NoOne: are you asking or answering ?